# Clearing an SFML scene with a partially transparent color

Tags: 2d, sfml, transparency, scene

Is there way to clear a scene with a transparency (alpha) value, in pure SFML?

I'm trying to clear with `rgba(0,0,0,128)` so the previous frame still partially shows through, which would create a motion blur effect.

I tried `window->clear(Color(0,0,0,128));` but with no result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Clearing the scene" will not produce this motion blur, you want to draw your frames into a RenderTexture, then draw this texture onto the main screen with your Alpha Blending enabled. Never clear the screen except on window resize.